# Bundle external JavaScript files using MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, bundling-and-minification

I have diffrent scripts online in a url:

externalurl/inte/common/js/script1.js

externalurl/inte/common/js/script2.js

externalurl/inte//common/js/script3.js

externalurl/inte//common/js/script4.js

externalurl/inte//common/js/script15.js

How can I create a javascript bundle for external javascript not in my solution?

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/inte").Include(
            "http://url/inte/common/js/script1.js",
            "http://url/inte/common/js/script2.js",
            "http://url/inte/common/js/script2.js));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use CDN jQuery you should enable CDN support `bundles.UseCdn = true;`

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
                jqueryCdnPath).Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
}
```